# jooq returns date without time for Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, date, jooq

I’m using Jooq v3.1.0 and have a problem with Oracle Date column. An Oracle procedure called by Jooq returns only date info without time (e.g.: “31.08.2018”. I expected “31.08.2018 18:44:05”)

I tried the following workaround

```
<database>
  <!-- Use this flag to force DATE columns to be of type TIMESTAMP -->
  <dateAsTimestamp>true</dateAsTimestamp>

  <!-- Define a custom binding for such DATE as TIMESTAMP columns -->
  <forcedTypes>
    <forcedType>
      <userType>java.sql.Timestamp</userType>
      <binding>org.jooq.impl.DateAsTimestampBinding</binding>
      <types>DATE</types>
    </forcedType>
  </forcedTypes>
</database>
```

But it did not work throwing the following error:
org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.1.0:generate for parameter userType: Cannot find 'userType' in class org.jooq.util.jaxb.ForcedType

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: There had been many fixes in this and other areas since jOOQ 3.1 - I strongly suggest upgrading to 3.11, the currently latest version

Answer (score 0):

According to jOOQ [configuration](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-date-as-timestamp/) custom binding is not needed. `dateAsTimestamp` flag should be enough to have it working.